# How to add patterns into stacked and bar-side-by-side in ggplot ggppatern

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset (tidysym) with variables site, proportion and majortype for 2 years (2017 and 2019). I would like to make stacked bar plots of the column proportion, coloring by major types for each site (with site in the x axis). And I would like to have the bars of each year side by side.
Sorry, I am not sure how to provide the dataset, so I am just adding more explanation below:

site= categorical variable (1_1, 1_2, 1_3, 2_1, 2_2, 2_3...)
majortype= categorical variable (C15,C17, D4, ..)
proportion= proportion of major types (multiple major types per sample. Sum of all the major types present in a sample in a site adds to 1)
year= categorical variable (2017, 2019)

Here is what I came up with:

```
colors2<- c("#7D0025", "#BE1D00" ,"#EB5500", "#F39300")

label<-c("1_1","", "1_2", "","1_3","", "2_1","", "2_2", "")

mx4 = ggplot(tidysym, aes(x = interaction(year, site), alpha=year, fill = majortypes, y =proportion)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.9, position= position_stack()) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(0.5,2.5,4.5,6.5,8.5,10.5, 12.5),color= "white", size=3)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 3, colour = "black", vjust = 0.5, hjust =-0.05), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 7),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 7), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 7),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        legend.position ="bottom",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 7, colour = "black"),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.3, 'cm'), legend.margin=margin(-0.4,0,0,0,unit="cm"))  + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  labs(x = "", y = "Relative proportion", fill = "ITS2 types") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors2) +
 scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.5,1))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1)); mx4
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeYE1.png)

It is hard to differentiate the years by using alpha. I would like to differentiate the years from each other by using patterns instead. And I would like to have different spacings, so that the same site has a bar for 2017 and 2019 closer to each other. I have tried to use ggpattern, but I could not find an example of stacked bar plot and interaction in x. Suggestions?

Comment: To share a snippet of your data type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could e.g. do `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 20))` for the first twenty rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether patterns are the right way to go. Anyway, to add patterns to your plot via `ggpattern` you could simply switch to `geom_col/bar_pattern` and map `year` on the `pattern` aesthetic.

However, to add some space between sites I would suggest to make use of faceting. To this end map `year` on `x` and facet by `site`. Afterwards you could use `theme` and `facet` options to style your plot such as to mimic a `non-facetted` plot. And of course could you add patterns to this plot too.

Making use of some random example data to mimic your real data try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)
#> Loading required namespace: memoise

colors2 <- c("#7D0025", "#BE1D00", "#EB5500", "#F39300")

ggplot(tidysym, aes(x = year, y = proportion, fill = majortypes, pattern = year)) +
  geom_col_pattern(pattern_size = .25) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors2) +
  facet_wrap(~site, nrow = 1, strip.position =  "bottom") +
  theme(
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background.x = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 3),
    panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "pt"),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 3),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 7),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 7),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 7),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.text = element_text(size = 7, colour = "black"),
    legend.key.size = unit(0.3, "cm"), 
    legend.margin = margin(-0.4, 0, 0, 0, unit = "cm")
  ) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Relative proportion", fill = "ITS2 types") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1, override.aes = list(pattern = "none")),
         pattern = guide_legend(nrow = 1, override.aes = list(fill = NA)))
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)

tidysym <- data.frame(
  year = rep(c(2017, 2019), each = 6),
  site = paste(rep(1:2, each = 3), 1:3, sep = "_"),
  majortypes = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 48 * 4, replace = TRUE)
)
tidysym <- tidysym %>%
  count(year, site, majortypes) %>%
  group_by(year, site) %>%
  mutate(proportion = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(year = factor(year))
```